# How to use a .out Kraken output format

Tags: format-conversion

I was given some Kraken output files but the file extension is .out. I know how to use .KREPORT files but not the .out file. Is there any way convert it to a KREPORT file or what do you recommend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The extension of a file does not determine its content. What is the format of your .out files?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If I read the file using Notepad++ I can see something like:

C   A00700:50 342 120|120 0:79 821:1 0:36 |:| A:1 0:58 821:4 0:53
U   A00700:50 342 139|106 0:69 226186:4 0:7 226186:5 0:31 |:| A:1 0:25 818:3 0:45

Is it useful?

Thanks.